# Problem using unicode in File.WriteAllText

Tags: c#

I have some raw data (xml) which I definitely receive containing unicode. I write them to a file using:

```
File.WriteAllText
```

This seems to remove/change unicode characters. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: This should not be a problem because by default `WriteAllText()` is using UTF8 encoding - sure you don't have a problem elsewhere? Please post some code

Comment: @BrokenGlass you might be right - it could also be XElement.ToString() ... is this the right way to get the unicode string from an xelement?

Comment: @BrokenGlass Not true. I had the same problem and added Encoding.UTF8 as 3rd parameter and now Unicode characters are not lost while saving with WriteAllText.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143376.aspx) overload which allows you to specify an encoding - just give it the same encoding of the original data.

Answer (score 15):

You can specify the encoding:

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, xml, Encoding.Unicode);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the proper encoding, which is the 3rd parameter.

```
File.WriteAllText(file, contents, encoding);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can specify the Encoding as parameter for the WriteAllText function, see the available overloads :)